# How do I get my variables in this pandas statement?

Tags: python, pandas, string-formatting

I'm trying to append new values to a pandas series inside a while loop.

But I'm getting a syntax error on the string formatting...

```
 import pandas as pd

 sClose = pd.Series()

 close = history['candles'][0]['closeMid']
 time = history['candles'][0]['time']

 sClose = s.Close.append(pd.Series(%s,index=[%s]))% (close, time)
```

How do i dynamically put new values inside the appended series during each loop?

Comment: The `%s` you're using is only for within a quoted string, not an open statement as you show.

Comment: I've never seen string formatting outside of a string.

Comment: You have not given enough information here.  Where is the loop?  What is `s`? Your `%s` statements are outside of strings, are you trying to format a string there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use quote around `%s`.

Something like this would do the trick:

```
close_str = '%s' % (close, )
time_str = '%s' % (time, )
sClose = sClose.append(pd.Series(close_str,index=[time_str]))
```

but not sure why you need to transtype to string. If `close` and `time` are numbers (or datetime), you can simply do:

```
sClose = sClose.append(pd.Series(close,index=[time]))
```

Answer (score 2):

As the `%s` is only used within quoted strings ('string' formatting), you can use the variable names directly in the final statement instead of putting a meta-variable to hold the place for then.

```
sClose = s.Close.append(pd.Series(close,index=[time]))
```